# How to disable the MSHTML cache in C++?

Tags: c++, mshtml

I do not know how to disable the web pages cache in my application which embed a Web Browser thanks to MSHTML.

I have googled it... MSDNed it... But still not able to find an answer...
Does someone know how to do it ?

Thanks in advance for all you answers.

**EDIT** : I now catch the `DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL` event in my `Invoke()` function.

I try to set pVarResult as following, but I do not get any result (the IE cache is still be in use to display any web pages.. I want to disable it.)

```
pVarResult->vt = VT_I4;
pVarResult->lVal = DLCTL_DLIMAGES | DLCTL_VIDEOS | DLCTL_BGSOUNDS | DLCTL_PRAGMA_NO_CACHE;
```

Comment: @Eugen : Not sure what does it mean "Serve the pages"... But, I am just displaying them in my application using the IE rendering engine.

Comment: if it was your app as the web server you could've used the Cache-Control HTTP header (assuming you do only HTTP traffic).
The info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041(v=VS.85).aspx#Controlling_Download_and_Execution especially (especially the DLCTL_RESYNCHRONIZE and DLCTL_PRAGMA_NO_CACHE part) may be helpful...